# How to wire authentication with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am following the documentation from [Spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) to setup user authentication using Spring Boot.

Here are the files in question:

```
MvcConfig.java

package com.*********.*******;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
package com.*********.*******;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

How can I eliminate the home.html file and wire it so that localhost:808 takes the user directly to the login which, if successful, brings them to the hello.html file?

If I change the default controller to the following code, then it just enters a loop of the login page because the login takes you to the previous page you were trying to access. How can I instead have it send the user to hello.html?

```
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
```

I apologize if this post is worded poorly. If there is anything I can add for clarity, please don't hesitate to ask and I will make any corrections.

Comment: remove the `antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()` so every access will redirected to `login

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai Okay, so removed that line and the login still just loops back to itself in a never-ending login loop.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai same result.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I just closed down inteilij and restarted it and it worked... not sure why. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove the line `.antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()` so all urls are protected and redirected to login.

```
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```